# Jenkins - docker credentials fail

Tags: jenkins, ubuntu-18.04, credentials, docker-registry

Using Jenkins 2.249.1 on ubuntu 18.04, Docker version 19.03.13

I have created `dkr-pwd` as secret text:

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'dkr-pwd', variable: 'dkr-pwd')]) {
              sh "docker login -u my-id -p {dkr-pwd}"
}
```

Also tried

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'dkr-id-pwd', passwordVariable: 'dkr-p', usernameVariable: 'dkr-id')]) {
            sh "docker login -u {dkr-id} -p {dkr-p}"
      }
```

Both fail - `unauthorized: incorrect username or password`. I know my id/pwd are correct- if I don't use credentials - send my pwd as plain text it works:
`sh "docker login -u my-id -p dkr-pwd"`

Tried recreating credentials etc- but no success.

Credentials Binding Plugin - 1.23, Credentials Plugin - 2.3.13

Comment: did you get this to work ?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'dockerhub', passwordVariable: 'pass', usernameVariable: 'user')]) {
                    
       sh "docker login --username=${user} --password=${pass}"
       sh "docker push username/imagename:latest"
}
```

Comment: I am not seeing the login into dockerhub step here?

Comment: I was essentially doing the same thing and it was not working  `sh "docker login -u my-id -p {dkr-pwd}"`

Answer (score 0):

Use $ for dkr-pwd in you command as below:

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'dkr-pwd', variable: 'dkr-pwd')]) {
       sh "docker login -u my-id -p ${dkr-pwd}"
}
```